# how to share resources between trunks in SVN?

Tags: svn

We have two projects which share the same common files.

E.g.

parentproj/subproj1/trunk/common/a.js

parentproj/subproj2/trunk/common/a.js

We will either modify a.js in subproj1 and then need to later copy it to subproj2, or visa versa.

We cant separate common out into its own SVN project with its own trunk, as then we will not be able to checkout the subproj and get it.  In CVS, we would solve this very easily by putting common in one of the two projects, then creating a symbolic link to it in project 2 on the CVS server.

So we have the above scenario with two projects each with their own copy of the same common files.  The next problem is how to merge the changes back from 1 to 2 or 2 to 1.  Eclipse cant do this, as it says "cannot perform operation with resources that are related to different project structures".  Tortiose SVN cant do it because you cant open two separate directories at the same time.  If you try and use tortoise to "copy" the modified files from one project to the other, it says it already exists.

We have set subproj1 to be the nominal master, and did an svn copy to subproj2.  But this does not help us I believe.

Currently, we manually cut and paste the changes for each updated common file using eclipse, then commit the changes.

This means the version numbers are different in the two different projects, even though it is the same file with the same contents.

Any ideas?

Currently we dont have or use command line SVN, as remembering and getting correct the long URL paths to tag/copy files seems too risky, but would consider it if the only way.

Our code is mostly js files, with some asp and html

If we were using CVS, we would only need to have one project (the parent), with a "game1" and a "game2" directory underneath, and one common dir.  This is because CVS allows you to branch and tag based on directory, where as SVN can only sanely branch/tag/merge the entire trunk.  The trunk dir totally gets in the way of eclipse, as it means we cant checkout both projects in one go, we have to separately checkout each project so we dont get the trunk dirs in the path.

Answer (score 1):

With TortoiseSVN you don't need to open two directories. Just select merge on one of them and select URL of another directory as merge source.

As for separating it - you can separate common stuff into third place and branch it into every sub-project.

Comment: Hi, they are in the same repo.  We would like both projects to always get the latest version, but if we had to manually update the dependent revision we could do that.  We just need a way to merge the changes without having to do it line by line by hand.

Comment: my bad, the eclise error is actually: cannot perform operation with resources that are related to different project structures

Comment: Interesing idea about common having its own trunk.  If I then branch to  the dependent projects, I have the same issue of how to merge back.  Is it ok to have a trunk which contains sub dirs which are branches from other projects?

Comment: if you right click on one a.js, select merge in tortoise SVN, it they asks to choose "merge range of revisions", "reintegrate branch" or "merge 2 different trees".  Should I be using reintegrate branch, or merge different trees?  Should I do this from proj1 a.js, or proj2 a.js, or doese it matter (proj2 was the branch).

Comment: Here you can find description of merging in branches: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html - likely it's better than I can fit in a comment. As for merging on files - if it's completely independent on the rest it may be OK, but if common stuff has interdependencies it's better to branch and merge on level of directory containing all common files.

Answer (score 1):

> We cant separate common out into its own SVN project with its own trunk, as then we will not be able to checkout the subproj and get it.

But you **must to can**: read and use svn:externals. If you share **the whole common dir**, externals can live in separate repo. If you share **common files only**, SVN must be 1.6+, externals target must be in the same repo, as source